# How do I properly click an element in Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click an element, for example "AH", in this [page](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/serie-a/internacional-santos-vcGTTAKH/). I use the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/serie-a/internacional-santos-vcGTTAKH/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
element_to_click = driver.find_element_by_link_text("AH")
element_to_click.click()
```

The problem is that after the element is clicked and the new page is loaded, it goes back to the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus the element and call `click_and_hold` action (worked for me):

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element_to_click).click_and_hold(element_to_click).perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

[alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) , that works. 
Just to add to the discussion here

[image]

So on mouse down it is invoking onClick for the uid(4), when we do a normal click on the element we do not realize that it worked on `mouse down` not on `mouse click`.

Thats why when we are using webdriver to do element.click() on it, this does not work and when we use Actions class to simulate mouse down using `click_and_hold`, It works !!